# How to get an EventHandler from a Castle-based DynamicProxy (and call subscribers if any) via Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, inotifypropertychanged, castle-dynamicproxy, eventhandler

I am trying to use GetField() in order to get to an EventHandler from a Castle-based dynamicproxy of a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.
However:

myObject.GetType().GetField( "PropertyChanged", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance ) returns a null.

Does anyone know of any special tricks / method for getting to an EventHandler from a class / dynamic proxy of a class (and call any subscribers) via Reflection?

Comment: Are you sure `PropertyChanged` is the field? Sounds like it's a name of event, which is not a field. I'd suggest you to get and printout all the fields first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the sample how to get `PropertyChanged` event via reflection and fire it.
Should work for any type, even for Castle-based dynamic proxy.  The only requirement is that `PropertyChanged` exists.
Code:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class FooDerived : Foo
    { }

```
internal class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string someProperty;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someProperty; }
        set
        {
            someProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new FooDerived();
        instance.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Property '{0}' has been changed!", e.PropertyName);

        FireEventOn(instance: instance,
                    eventName: "PropertyChanged",
                    createEventArgs: () => new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName: "SomeProperty"));
    }

    // only not null reference to instance is needed
    // so will work on any not null instance
    // of any type
    private static void FireEventOn(object instance, string eventName, Func<object> createEventArgs)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        FieldInfo e = GetEvent(eventName, instance.GetType(), lookupWholHierarchy: true);
        var eventDelegate = (MulticastDelegate)e.GetValue(instance);
        if(eventDelegate == null)
        {
             // nothing to call
             return;
        }

        foreach (Delegate d in eventDelegate.GetInvocationList())
        {
            Console.Write("Dynamically firing the event: ");
            d.Method.Invoke(d.Target, new[] { instance, createEventArgs() });
        }
    }

    private static FieldInfo GetEvent(string eventName, Type type, bool lookupWholHierarchy = false)
    {
        if (!lookupWholHierarchy)
        {
            return type.GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var t in GetHierarchy(type))
            {
                var e = t.GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                if (e != null)
                {
                    return e;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetHierarchy(Type startFrom)
    {
        var current = startFrom;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current;
            current = current.BaseType;
        }
    }


   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Updated the code: added (pretty dumb) logic for looking up for the event through the whole inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: As turned out my code did not work for the classes where `PropertyChanged` event was declared in base classes. So I added pretty dumb logic for searching for the event on base classes. Could you please try it and let us know the result?

Comment: Awesome!  Worked like a charm...   (Somehow I must have overlooked one of the details in "climbing the hierarchy earlier)  You may want to be aware that your FireEventOn() method will most likely crash / throw an exception if nobody subscribed to the event unless you add a check for eventDelegate != null before trying to call GetInvocationList().    (Minor implementation detail.  Gladly buy you beverage of choice if we ever meet in "real world!")

Comment: @Wonderbird, glad that helped. Also, I added `eventDelegate != null` check.

Comment: @aleksy.berezan. Cool!  Pretty neat to have INotifyPropertyChanged and possibly other "post setter" processes like business rule checking "automagically" implemented consistently on dozens of properties in  hundreds of classes through creative use of dynamicproxies.  Thanks again for your help!